# How to use pinia getter in setup ? (with a wrapped defineStore and async fetching)

Tags: asynchronous, vuejs3, pinia

I don't succeed to use a Pinia getter properly in the setup part.

It's working when I use the getter directly in the  part, but not in the  part.

Here is my (simplified) pinia store :

```
export const useCharactersStore = () => {
  const charactersStoreBuilder = defineStore("characters", {
    state: (): State => ({
      characters: {},
    }),
    getters: {
      getCharacter(state) {
        return (characterId: string) => state.characters[characterId];
      },
    },
    actions: {
      async fetchCharacters() {
        this.characters = {
          1: "Character 1",
          2: "Character 2",
        };
      },
    },
  });
  const charactersStore = charactersStoreBuilder();
  charactersStore.fetchCharacters(); // async fetching
  return charactersStore;
```

And here is my usage :

```
<script setup>
import { useCharactersStore } from "@/stores/characters";
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";

const characterId = 1;

const characterStore = useCharactersStore();

// Various alternatives :

// Don't work
const { getCharacter } = storeToRefs(characterStore);
const character = getCharacter.value(characterId);

// Don't work
const character = characterStore.getCharacter(characterId);

// Don't work
const character = characterStore.getCharacter(characterId);

// Work
const getCharacter = characterStore.getCharacter;
</setup>

<template>
  <pre>
    <!-- Don't work -->
    {{ character }}

    <!-- Work -->
    {{ getCharacter(characterId) }}
  </pre>
</template>
```

I've also tried with character as a `ref`, with its value updated with a watch, and various things. I'm absolutely lost :/

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambiguous. I do not know what you mean by.

> It's working when I use the getter directly in the part, but not in the part.

However, I made a slight modification to your code. For me, this works.

```js
// CharactersStore.ts
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useCharactersStore = () => {
  const charactersStoreBuilder = defineStore('CharactersStore', {
    state: () => {
      return {
        characters: {} as Record<number | string, string | number>,
      }
    },
    actions: {
      // async is irrelevant here. You can use setTimeout to simulate async here.
      async fetchCharacters() {
        this.characters = {
          1: 'Character 1',
          2: 'Character 2',
        }
      },
    },
    getters: {
      getCharacterByID: (state) => (characterId: string | number) =>
        state.characters[characterId],
    },
  })

  const charactersStore = charactersStoreBuilder()
  charactersStore.fetchCharacters() // async fetching
  return charactersStore
}
```

#### The Test page I used.

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'

const c = useCharactersStore()
const characterId = 1 // even though it works, It is not reactive.
const character = c.getCharacterByID(characterId)

const { getCharacterByID: getCharacterWithStoreRef } = storeToRefs(c)
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Test page</h1>
    <div>
      <pre>
        Get character by Id : {{ c.getCharacterByID(characterId) }}
        character {{ character }}
        getCharacterWithStoreRef {{ getCharacterWithStoreRef(characterId) }}
      </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

### Result

[image: Character result]

**Test the solution provided**
Feel free to let me know if it works for you. Happy coding

### Additional information

- Read more about [Passing arguments to getters in Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/getters.html#passing-arguments-to-getters)